# Tensor product of modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, free-modules

Please give me a hint for this problem.

Let $R$ be a ring, and $I$ a right ideal of $R$. Show if $M$ is a left $R$-module, then
$$ f  \   \colon (R/I) \otimes_{R} M \to  M/IM$$ 
defined by $ f((r+I) \otimes m) = rm + IM$ is an isomorphism of commutative groups.

And show that if $L$ is a left ideal, then 
$$ (R/I) \otimes _{R} (R/L) \cong R/(I+L)$$
as commutative groups.

Comment: Show that $M/IM$ satisfies the universal property of $(R/I)\otimes M$.

Comment: What you need to master to do anything with tensor products is learn how to *write down mappings out of a tensor product*. Think of a natural map $R/I \times R/L \rightarrow R/(I+L)$ -- there is an obvious one you should think of -- and check that it has the right universal property to lead to a map $R/I \otimes_R (R/L) \rightarrow R/(I+L)$.  Then define a map $R \rightarrow (R/I) \otimes_R (R/L)$ in the other direction, check it kills $I+L$, and then you get a map $R/(I+L) \rightarrow (R/I) \otimes_R (R/L)$. Now check the composite of the maps in both directions is the identity.

Answer (score 0):

If we tensor with $M$ the short exact sequence $0\to I\to R\to R/I\to 0$ and consider the exact sequence $0\to IM\to M\to M/IM\to 0$, we obtain a commutative diagram of abelian groups with exact rows
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
{} @. I\otimes_RM @>>> R\otimes_RM @>>> (R/I)\otimes_R M @>>> 0 \\
@. @VaVV @VbVV @VcVV @. \\
0 @>>> IM @>>> M @>>> M/IM @>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$
We have $a(r\otimes x)=rx$, $b(r\otimes x)=rx$ and $c((r+I)\otimes x)=rx+IM$. Note that $a$ is surjective and $b$ is an isomorphism. A very simple diagram chasing shows that $c$ is an isomorphism as well.

For the second case, we need to compute
$$
I(R/L)=(IR+L)/L=(I+L)/L
$$
and so
$$
(R/L)\big/I(R/L)=(R/L)\big/((I+L)/L)\cong R/(I+L)
$$
by the homomorphism theorem.